# If values of combobox remains blank then must have to insert into MS Access

Tags: java, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have 4 columns in database and I have to insert items of combobox into those columns.  I tried below code but it only works when 4 items in combobox are inserted.  If I insert only 2 items into combobox then remaining two must have to be inserted NULL.

```
if(e.getSource()==btn_save)
{
try{

     Connection con;

     DriverManager.registerDriver(new sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver());

     Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

     con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:dsnproj","","");

     Statement s1 = con.createStatement();

     String q1="insert dest,route1,route2,route3,route4 into trans_dest values(
                '"+cmb_dest.getSelectedItem()+"',
                '"+cmb_route.getItem(0)+"',
                '"+cmb_route.getItem(1)+"',
                '"+cmb_route.getItem(2)+"',
                '"+cmb_route.getItem(3)+"')";

     s1.execute(q1);


     }

     catch(Exception ae)
     {
         System.out.println(ae);
     }
  }
}
```

When I insert two items and two items remain blank, then I get this error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 >= 2
>   java.lang.StackTraceElement;@1d8957f

Comment: Add the entire stack trace here ..

Comment: please help me for this query...